# Triangle length check

Tags: python

I am looking to check if a triangle is valid (two shorter lengths added together are greater than longest length) and then print whether it is equilateral, isosceles or scalene. I have my code for classifying the triangle into the 3 types and these work but when I add the validity line it prints all triangles are impossible. Is there a better way to add this line?

```
length_1=input("Enter whole number 1-1000")
length_2=input("Enter whole number 1-1000")
length_3=input("Enter whole number 1-1000")
if (length_1>=length_2+length_3) or (length_2>=length_1+length_3) or (length_3>=length_1+length_2):
print("triangle is invalid")
```

Comment: The error calculations that are being done are done on `length_1`, `length_2`, and `length_3`, without turning them to integers.  You will need to add them as `int`s like how it has been done for other comparisons.

Comment: If you do the conversion to integer before you do the calculations then `if int(length_1) < 1 or int(length_1) >100:` can be written as `if not 1 <= length1 <= 100` (and according to the text `100` should be `1000` anyway).

Answer (score 3):

length_1, length_2 & length_3 all are input as string by default.

Convert them to int/float the start only:

```
length_1=int(input("Enter whole number 1-1000"))
length_2=int(input("Enter whole number 1-1000"))
length_3=int(input("Enter whole number 1-1000"))
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
length_1=input("Enter whole number 1-1000")
length_2=input("Enter whole number 1-1000")
length_3=input("Enter whole number 1-1000")
print("Entered values:", length_1,length_2,length_3)
length_1, length_2, length_3 = int(length_1), int(length_2), int(length_3)
#use exit for invalid lengths less than 0 or more than 1000
if int(length_1) < 1 or int(length_1) >1000:
    exit("All of the sides need to within the range 1-1000")
if int(length_2) < 1 or int(length_2) >1000:
    exit("All of the sides need to within the range 1-1000")
if int(length_3) < 1 or int(length_3) > 1000:
        exit("All of the sides need to within the range 1-1000")
#if triangle is equilateral sides are all equal
if (length_1>=length_2+length_3) or (length_2>=length_1+length_3) or (length_3>=length_1+length_2):
    print("triangle is impossible")
elif length_1==length_2==length_3:
    print("Triangle is equilateral")
#right angled triangle a**2+b**2=c**2
elif int(length_1)**2+int(length_2)**2==int(length_3)**2:
    print("Triangle is right angled")
#if triangle is isosceles 2 sides are equal
elif length_1==length_2 or length_2==length_3 or length_1==length_3:
    print("Triangle is isosceles")
#using else to say triangle is scalene
else:
    print("Triangle is scalene")
```

You need to turn the `length_` variables into integers before you can do calculations on them.
You were doing that in a line but not using them later on.

```
length_1, length_2, length_3 = int(length_1), int(length_2), int(length_3)
```

This is the required line

Answer (score 1):

i have changed the line

```
    if (length_1>=length_2+length_3) or (length_2>=length_1+length_3) or (length_3>=length_1+length_2):
```

to

```
    if (sorted_lengths[0]+sorted_lengths[1]<sorted_lengths[2]):
```

then it works